# How we show pages in dropdown

Tags: menus

I show the all `menu` which i have on the top in `dropdown` style when site is open in mobiles.
I successfully display them in dropdown style but the problem is that how can i indend my subpages. or make parent pages bolg is any way to do that, my code is

```
<nav id="nav-mobile" role="navigation">
                <select id="mob_menu" name="page-dropdown"> 
                 <option value="">
                <?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?></option> 
                 <?php 
                  $pages = get_pages(); 
                  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                    $option = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
                    $option .= $page->post_title;
                    $option .= '</option>';
                    echo $option;
                  }
                 ?>
                </select>

                </nav>
```

Comment: You indent and change the `font-weight` (bold) the output with CSS. There doesn't seem to be anything WordPress specific to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wp_dropdown_pages()`:

```
print '<form action="' . home_url() . '">';
wp_dropdown_pages();
print '<input type=submit></form>';
```

You get a `select` field with proper indentation, and clicking on the button will send the user to that page.

[image]